# Difference between Law of total probability and case-distinction formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am currently studying the book Stochastics, Introduction to probability and statistics written by Hans-Otto Georgii. I am a bit confused about a specific theorem.

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\Omega=\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$ an at most countable partition of $\Omega$ into pairwise disjoint events $B_i\in \mathbb{F}$. Then the following holds

(a) Case distinction formula. For every $A\in \mathbb{F}$,
$P(A)=\sum_{i\in I}P(B_i)P(A\lvert B_i)$

I have the following questions:
If $P(B_i)=0$ for a specific i, then $P(A\lvert B_i)$ is not defined. Do we just assume these terms are omitted from the equation ?
Isnt this formula exactly the Law of total probability ?

Comment: If $P(B_i)=0$, then $i \not \in I$. Thus it is not part of the sum.

Comment: @callculus42 I don't know where you get that from. Where in the set-up does it say that $P(B_i)>0$ for all $i\in I$?

Comment: Yes, this result is often called the law of total probability, or sometimes the partition theorem. And yes, to make sense of this in cases where $P(B_i)=0$ for some $i$, you can use the convention that $P(A|B_i)P(B_i)$ is taken to be $0$ for all such $i$. (Which makes sense since we want $P(A|B_i)P(B_i)$ to be the same as $P(A\cap B_i)$.)